# Change drawable xml content programmatically

Tags: android, xml, listview

We have a checkbox inside a listview whose background image needs to change according the content of the listview item, like the gmail email listview.

Our approach right now is to set the checkbox background by using the `android:button="@drawable/startcheckbox"` option where `startcheckbox` is an xml in the drawable folder containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/star_rate_white_54x54" />
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/star_rate_yellow_54x54" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_rate_white_54x54" /> <!-- default state -->
    </selector>
```

My question is how can we change the `state_checked="false"` and `state_checked="true"` from inside the fragment where the listview is being populated.

Comment: you cannot change the content of an xml resource file programmatically on android.

Comment: use a different resource file

Comment: see `StateListDrawable` documentation

Answer (score 0):

Mutate the drawable via Drawable.mutate() then you can change whatever you want.

In general though I do find that if you want to do anything programmatic with a drawable other than scale it, you're better off avoiding xml and using code and custom drawables.

Comment: not really, `StateListDrawable` has very limited API, in fact you can only add a new state to: `addState (int[] stateSet, Drawable drawable)`

Comment: Ive done it before, I'll see if I can dig up the code.  I think I overrode the same state?